# how to use maxmind geoip2 in Spark Streaming?

Tags: streaming, geoip

I want to use maxmind geoip2 to process IP info with Spark Streaming, but I could not find any example?

For spark, I can use sc.addFile(gepip.mmdb) and mapPartitions with https://github.com/Sanoma-CDA/maxmind-geoip2-scala or  https://github.com/Sanoma-CDA/maxmind-geoip2-scala.
Spark Streaming does not supper sc.addFile, so I cannot use mapPartitions. Any idea, thanks.

Comment: did you get any solution for this issue? if so please share with me.